# RTSP stream of h264 data not working in vlc Android

Tags: android, h.264, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I have build the vlc for android on Ubuntu 14.10. I am able play the local videos on my tab, but when I try play rtsp stream of h264 data, nothing plays back.I tried it with two different local streams and one rtsp test link rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

I was able to play all these in vlc android I got from play store. I saw the logs, there are some errors like

```
01-20 11:38:28.687: E/ACodec(25471): Failed to allocate buffers after transitioning to IDLE state (error 0x80000000)
01-20 11:38:28.687: E/MediaCodec(25471): Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
01-20 11:38:28.687: I/ACodec(25471): [OMX.MARVELL.VIDEO.HW.CODA7542DECODER] Now Loaded
01-20 11:38:28.687: W/VLC(25471): mediacodec decoder: Exception occurred in MediaCodec.start
```

I feel its not able to open window to display stream. In all 3 cases, it shows this error in end

```
01-20 12:17:25.277: D/VLC(28113): core vout display: looking for vout display module matching "androidwindow": 4 candidates
01-20 12:17:25.317: D/VLC/AudioService(28113): Updating widget
```

Any help? I am attaching the logs links

local stream 1 : http://pastebin.com/9zdgSgK1

Local Stream 2 : http://pastebin.com/cn9FDhr5

Test Stream :    http://pastebin.com/GjgY4t2Q

Device : Samsung Tab 4 2013 Model

Android version : 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but when I see your query and check on developer.android.com got to know that RTSP stream of h264 data supports only 3GPP (.3gp),MPEG-4 (.mp4),MPEG-TS (.ts, AAC audio only, not seekable, Android 3.0+) formats while you have used .MOV format. Can you try with suggested format?

Comment: ok I will do that. But I think it works as I am able to play the same stream with vlc android client from play store

Comment: @Deego  : do you know some test link for these formats. I am trying and not able to find any working link (I find many links, but all are dead).

Comment: I don't have any as of now. If I'll get any, will share it with you.